# Silverlight toolkit datagrid mouse over problem

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I have datagrid and noticed strange bug:

I set HeadersVisibility="All". And when move mouse from row header to right (to first cell(row) in grid) you will notice that row mouseover state will not be fired.

How can i change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to listen on the cell's "mouseOver" and then determine the row to which it belongs.

see this question for more details :

[Silverlight 3 Datagrid: Get row/item on MouseOver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866189/silverlight-3-datagrid-get-row-item-on-mouseover)

Comment: well, you're stuck.
the fact is that the rowHeader is allready in the row, so when you move from rowHeader to first cell of Row, you don't change the row, so the mouseOver event on the row will not be fire again (it has already been fired when you entered the Row at the same time as entering the rowHeader...
other option would be to listen on the mouseOver changed on the rowHeader, and test inside if the mouse is still over the row although it is not on the rowHeader anymore (I'm pretty sure you can do this in Xaml, but it's not simple)